# Can't seem to connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, debian

I have the problem of connecting with mysql on my debian server. I run `mysql -u root` and get the error message:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
```

So I did and I ran the command `sudo find / -type s` and got

```
/run/proftpd.sock
/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Not `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`!

Im simply trying to set up a database server to test it. What should I do?

Comment: can you try `sudo service mysql start`?

Comment: @Eray I got: [ ok ] Starting MySQL database server: mysqld ..
[info] Checking for tables which need an upgrade, are corrupt or were 
not closed cleanly..

Comment: so your mysql server started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question would be better asked on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com).  However, the easiest way to do this (without confusing other Debian apps) would be to create (as root) a symbolic link to the sock file:

```
# ln -s /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Comment: I got: "ln: failed to create symbolic link `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock': File exists"

Comment: Sounds like your problem is fixed then.

Answer (score 0):

Connect with `mysql -u root -S /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`, this should work.